# Phrases that express "to look around nervously"

Tags: phrases, expressions

I'm trying to describe a situation where someone is on high alert, scanning his surroundings looking for potential threat.

It seems to me that "Look around" lacks the sense of tension I want. "Scan" feels strange in the context "one moment he was ____ around in search of threat, and the next [an incident happened]".

Thanks for your help!

Comment: why not just say, "his senses were on high alert"?

Comment: Look around edgily?

Comment: Unfortunately this site is devoted to *English*, not Japanese. Otherwise the answer could be [**きょろきょろ(見回す)**](http://www.flashcardmachine.com/onomatopoeia2.html) - defined there as *to look around nervously or restlessly*. You might consider something more circumlocutory, such as [*"His **eyes darted round** {the room}"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22his+eyes+darted+round%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl)

Comment: @FumbleFingers *darting* is an answer (I know because I thought of it before I saw your comment). Offer it.

Comment: @bib: It's not *much* of an answer (only *eyes* can "dart", and it ignores *pricking [up] one's ears*, or other senses put on high alert for danger). Maybe there's a more generic term we're not thinking of (yet).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I haven't seen a better one than *dart* so far. The OP's question seems to focus on eyes. Why not offer it, and if a better one comes along ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> He was casting his eyes warily about/around . . .

[cast
verb
2
direct {one's eyes or a look} at something.

"she cast down her eyes"](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+cast&oq=define+cast)

--Google search (define: operation)

[warily

adverb

cautiously; carefully.

"they walk warily down the street, terrified of being caught"


synonyms:   carefully, with care, cautiously, gingerly, circumspectly, charily, guardedly, on one's guard, on the alert, on the lookout, on the qui vive, attentively, heedfully, watchfully, vigilantly, observantly, alertly, cannily;](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+warily)

--Google search (define: operation)

As has already been suggested, *dart* is also an option for a verb, as in *his eyes darted around/about warily* and *nervously, guardedly, vigilantly, on alert* (some of which have also been already suggested) can be alternatives for *warily.*

Answer (score 0):

One moment he was alarmed to the sense of threat the next ...

Answer (score 0):

> On guard though he was, [an incident happened].

*on guard* -[TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+guard)

1. on (one's) guard (against someone or something)
   alert against someone or something.

Answer (score -1):

Glancing nervously ...  This is a sentence too.

Comment: Casting furtive glances..,

Comment: Perhaps you could try to substantiate your answer, rather than adding nonsensical remarks to meet character minimums. (There's a reason character minimums were implemented; namely, to discourage two-word answers.)